# Golang example not working for adding Activity

Tags: go, getstream-io

I have tried to get this to work and am growing more and more frustrated. I have used the examples in the docs but they are throwing errors.

Specifically this field:

```
To: [&UserFeed]
```

Throws this error:

```
does not compile: expected type, found ','
```

Here is code snippet:

```
getstream_client, err := getstream.New(&getstream.Config{
    APIKey:      os.Getenv("STREAM_API_KEY"),
    APISecret:   os.Getenv("STREAM_API_SECRET"),
    AppID:       os.Getenv("STREAM_APP_ID"),
    Location:    "us-west",
  })
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("ERR :", err)
  }

    UserFeed, err := getstream_client.FlatFeed("user", u.StreamId)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    GlobalFeed, err := getstream_client.FlatFeed("user", "global")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    activity := &getstream.Activity{
        Actor: UserFeed.FeedID(),
        ForeignID: uuid.New(),
        To: [&UserFeed],
        Verb: "attempt",
    };
    activity, err = GlobalFeed.AddActivity(activity);
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Comment: `[&UserFeed]` isn't legal syntax in go. If your adding an slice literal, which it looks like you're trying to do, then you need to do: `[]YourType{&UserFeed}` which reads as `a slice of your type which is initialized to only have a single value in it which is set to the provided value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TO field should look like this. Hope this helps someone:

```
To: []getstream.Feed{UserFeed}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and apologies for the confusion. I've updated some of the snippets on our Go documentation and just waiting for caching to expire so they'll go live soon.